# GXT Grid with multiple sources

Tags: gxt

I am trying to create a grid using GXT that contains data from multiple JSON sources.  I've been able to get the grid working with one source, but can't figure out how to add additional sources to the grid or the ListStore.

```
// ...
ScriptTagProxy<PagingLoadResult<ModelData>> proxy = 
     new ScriptTagProxy<PagingLoadResult<ModelData>>(url);
ModelType type = new ModelType();
type.setRoot("root");
type.addField("source");
type.addField("description");
JsonPagingLoadResultReader<PagingLoadResult<ModelData>> reader = 
     new JsonPagingLoadResultReader<PagingLoadResult<ModelData>>(type);
final PagingLoader<PagingLoadResult<ModelData>> loader = 
     new BasePagingLoader<PagingLoadResult<ModelData>>(proxy, reader);

ListStore<ModelData> store = new ListStore<ModelData>(loader);

final Grid<ModelData> grid = new Grid<ModelData>(store, cm);
add(grid);
// ...
```

Is there a way to add additional loaders to a GXT ListStore?  Ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one method of populating a grid with multiple remote sources is to use borrow from the article http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/using_gwt_for_json_mashups.html and create a 'mashup' class that populates a ListStore with the results as each response is returned.